# supervisord - automatically kills its spwaned processes

Tags: unix, java, process, supervisord

I am a new bee with Supervisord. And I am on Ubuntu.

My problem is, I have a script to spawn java process using "exec java -cp ....." as the only line in the script. This particular java process is a non-daemon process that runs for infinite time (as the "driver" is always up and running, I checked also it is working as expected if I invoke the start script directly).

But I have configured supervisord.conf file as

```
[program:mydriver]
command=/home/subho/Workshop/start.sh
directory=/home/subho/Workshop
startsecs=5
stdout_logfile=/home/subho/Workshop/Logs/out.log
stderr_logfile=/home/subho/Workshop/Sink/Logs/err.log
```

But when I start by 
    `./supervisord -c <path to my conf file>`

The process gets started properly and once it goes in running state, it automatically killed by supervisor itself. Below is the log,

```
2017-06-03 18:58:05,286 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2017-06-03 18:58:05,297 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-06-03 18:58:05,297 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any 
HTTP authentication checking
2017-06-03 18:58:05,297 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2017-06-03 18:58:05,298 INFO supervisord started with pid 19698
2017-06-03 18:58:06,300 INFO spawned: 'mydriver' with pid 19699
2017-06-03 18:58:11,671 INFO success: mydriver entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 5 seconds (startsecs)
2017-06-03 18:58:27,439 INFO waiting for mydriver to die
2017-06-03 18:58:27,465 INFO stopped: mydriver (exit status 143)
```

Why it is happening? the same is happening when I am starting tomcat or any other process as well.

Comment: Help in any aspect of the problem is appreciated since this is very important for me and i am running out of time..i am still strugling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the right reason or not. But this solved my problem.

I kept the conf file under a custom path. The default path of supervisor conf file is under /etc/supervisor/. When I used the default conf file (and added my custom conf file under /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myconf.conf), it worked as expected.